# Почему функция выводит undefined вместо фразы

Tags: javascript

Почему код выводит undefined вместо фразы, если задать index больше длины массива. По задумке он должен обнуляться. Где ошибка?

```
var eightBall = {
    index: 0,
    advice: ["yes", "no", "maybe", "not a chance"],
    shake: function() {
        this.index = this.index + 1;
        if (this.index >= this.advice.lenght) {
            this.index = 0;
        }
    },
    look: function() {
        return this.advice[this.index];
    }
};

eightBall.shake();

console.log(eightBall.look());
```

Comment: код из вопроса работает, может покажете код, который у вас не работает?

Comment: `lenght -> length`

Comment: @ThisMan, я вставил копию кода

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, не совсем понял что не так

Comment: опечатка у вас в слове, но по сути с одним вызовом все работает)

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, извиняюсь, уже заметил